# Angular: Using the providers array of a component imported from a different module

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-module, angular-dependency-injection

I have a `ViewerWidgetComponent` - selector `app-viewer-widget`, declared in and exported from `SharedModule`.

The `ViewerWidgetComponent` has a child component from a third party library: `AcMapComponent` - selector `ac-map`, where content is projected within `ac-map`:

```html
viewer-widget.component.html:

    <ac-map [mapId]="viewerId">
        <ng-container *ngIf="viewerInitialised | async">
            <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="content.templateRef"></ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    </ac-map>
```

Side note - template is used as content to be projected is conditionally rendered, found using custom `ProjectContentDirective` directive.

`ViewerWidgetComponent` has a `ViewerConfiguration` provider, required for the third party `AcMapComponent`

```js
viewer-widget.component.ts:

@Component({
  selector: 'app-viewer-widget',
  templateUrl: './viewer-widget.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./viewer-widget.component.scss'],
  providers: [ViewerConfiguration],
})
export class ViewerWidgetComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ContentChild(ProjectContentDirective) content!: ProjectContentDirective;
  public viewerInitialised = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  constructor(private viewerConfiguration: ViewerConfiguration) { 
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {    
    // other logic here...
    this.viewerInitialised.next(true);
  }
}
```

I am then importing this `ViewerWidgetComponent` into `ExploreModule` and using it in `PortalComponent`.

`PortalComponent` is declared in `ExploreModule`:

```js
portal.component.html:

<app-viewer-widget>

  <ng-template appProjectContent>
    <ac-layer>
      <ac-billboard-desc></ac-billboard-desc>
    </ac-layer>
  </ng-template>

</app-viewer-widget>
```

Now the problem here, is `ac-layer` is another third party component, which must be a child of the `ac-map` component, as it relies on the providers array from the `ac-map` component. Which it is, since it is in a template container and rendered via the `ViewerWidgetComponent`, but since the template is in another module, DI is not picking up the `ac-map` providers.

Snippet from third party `ac-map` component ts:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'ac-map',
  template: `
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `,
  providers: [
    CesiumService,
    several more...
    MapLayersService,
  ],
})
```

So Angular is throwing this error: `NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(ExploreModule)[MapLayersService -> MapLayersService -> MapLayersService -> MapLayersService]: NullInjectorError: No provider for MapLayersService!`

Since it can't find the required providers, as `ac-map` component is in a different module.

How can I forward the providers array within `ac-map`, a child of `ViewerWidgetComponent`, declared in `SharedModule`, to be used in the `PortalComponent`, which is in a different module?

Answer (score 1):

There's another way of creating dynamic component. If there was a running code snippet i could have tested but you can try this:

html

```
<ac-map [mapId]="viewerId" ProjectContentDirective>
</ac-map>
```

ts file:

```
 @ViewChild(ProjectContentDirective) content!: ProjectContentDirective;
  public viewerInitialised = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver:ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.viewerInitialised.subscribe(v=>{
      if(v==true){
        const viewContainerRef = this.content.viewContainerRef;
        viewContainerRef.clear();
        const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent<AcMacCopmponent>(this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(AcMacCopmponent));    
      }
    })
  }

  
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {    
    // other logic here...
    this.viewerInitialised.next(true);
  }
```